# How to avoid collision by redrawing the line in d3.js when it passes through another node?

Tags: svg, d3.js, collision-detection

we have an application based on D3.js where nodes are connected with edges(paths).

**Problem:**
The problem is the edge(path) is passing through the node when it is in between two nodes.

[image]

In the above pic, the connection is between the nodes A and C, but the line passes through node B.

**Expected output:**
My expected output is the path should detect the node in between and trace around the node if there is a collision
[image]

The above pic is the expected output.

I searched but couldn't find any resource related to this, can someone help me with a solution or a workaround?.

PS: we did not use force graph.

Comment: No, that's not possible as-is. There might be plugins or libraries that do this for you, but it's a complex piece of logic that is not natively included in d3

Comment: @RubenHelsloot thanks, if you come across or know a library do post it here :).

Comment: You could detect *whether* there is a collision using [kld-intersections](https://github.com/thelonious/kld-intersections), but how to respond to them is completely up to you in this case

Comment: @RubenHelsloot, thanks will check this lib, seems like a good place to start.

Comment: @KishorKumar can you post here your code that renders the nodes and edges?